# Переключение языка дебиан

Tags: linux, debian

У меня проблема сделал автоматический вход в систему debian 4.19.0-8-amd64 x86_64 Xfce.Столкнулся с тем что у меня не меняется раскладка клавиатуры.(т.е нажимаю на переключение клавиш но ничего не происходит.приходиться каждый раз удалять и снова ставить русский язык)

Comment: думаю, Вам нужно уточнить, какой DE вы используете - гном, кде, xfce и что именно используете для переключения клавиатуры

Comment: xface xface xface

Comment: anydesk ставил?

Comment: нет не ставил  его